# How to use OpenStreetMap in webpage via OSM URL without Leaflet, OpenLayers, etc?

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping

I want to know how I can interact with OpenStreetMap in a webpage via (only HTML, CSS, JavaScript) without Leaflet, OpenLayers, MapBox or anything like them (in backend or frontend). I am going to use pure OpenStreetMap only through URL.

For example in below code it seems I didn't run Leaflet but when I went to inspect webpage by DevTools I got Leaflet is running! And zoom control panel was belong to Leaflet.

[image]
[image]

I learned and used this question "**[openstreetmap-embedding-map-in-webpage-like-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925164/openstreetmap-embedding-map-in-webpage-like-google-maps)**" asked in stackoverflow already.

```
<iframe width="400" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=51.2016004294,35.6079433209,51.5569619459,35.7819296463&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
```

But when I changed code to different coordinate and webpage loaded again I saw map loaded perfect together with Leaflet control! Whereas I didn't write any code in page it will want to run Leaflet!

Comment: You included https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html which in turn includes Leaflet.

Comment: Ok, what should I do, if I want see osm without leaflet?

Comment: If you want some sort of interactive map view, then it is necessary to use some code to load tiles, zooming, etc. You can write this code itself, or use some 3rd party libraries, like leaflet, which is much easier and reliable...

Comment: In order to make a Leaflet-like viewer without Leaflet, you need to rewrite Leaflet, from scratch. This may be a significant level of effort.

Comment: Are you asking how you could just see a static map, with no interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid any external libraries then you have to load the tiles directly.

OMS's standard tile layer uses [TMS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) and uses the following URL scheme: [https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/$%7Bz%7D/$%7Bx%7D/$%7By%7D.png)

To show a specific location you have to specify the zoom level `z`, longitude `x` and latitude `y`. How to do this is explained at [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), including example implementations in various languages.

Example: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4409/2741.png

To implement panning you have to change `x` and `y` accordingly. To implement zooming you have to increase/decrease `z` and adapt `x` and `y` to match the new [subtile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Subtiles).

Comment: Thank you I tried this method but didn't get result "I got too many request" error message! I'll try again in other ways, but do you know how I can solve this kind of restriction?

Comment: Sure it has since it costs money to run these servers. See the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) for more information.